# How to make a full outer join in the same table?

Tags: ms-access

I have a single table with this schema:

```
 |code|time|fk|
 --------------
 |a   |0.1 |2 |
 |b   |0.2 |1 |
 |b   |0.3 |2 |
```

And I would want to make compare all the codes and give me something like this:

```
 |code|time_fk1|time_fk2|
 ------------------------
 |a   |null    |0.1     |
 |b   |0.2     |0.3     |
```

sql: `select code, time_fk1, time_fk2 from table2 as fk1 left join table2 as fk2 on fk1.code=fk2.code where (fk1.fk=1 or fk1.fk is null) and (fk2.fk=2 or fk2.fk is null)`

The goal is a full outer join: but im not complicating to much yet because not even a left/right join works

But access gives me only this with that query:

```
 |code|time_fk1|time_fk2|
 ------------------------
 |b   |0.2     |0.3     |
```

It acts exactly as it were a inner join! If I change the "left" in the above query for (right or inner the results are the same)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select code, SUM(time_fk1), SUM(time_fk2)
from

(   
(select code, time as time_fk1, 0
from table 
where fk=1)

UNION

(select code, 0,time as time_fk2
from table 
where fk=2)
) a

group by code
```

However, using this query b will come twice in the result if it has time against both fk's.

Comment: select code, sum(time_fk1), sum(time_fk2) from
(select code, time as time_fk1, 0 as time_fk2
from table2
where fk=1

UNION

(select code, 0 as time_fk1,time as time_fk2
from table2
where fk=2)) as a
group by code

this works aswell and I'm deleting the duplicate and not useful rows

Comment: @Totty sorry, but could not understand your point. The query you are mentioning in comment and query you asked in question, both are doing completely different things. SUM function changes the scenario.

Comment: no. pay attention. I've put zeros where you put the null. so when I sum the number is the same or 0. in this way I can get all the important row and join them on the same line. but is not really stable..

Comment: @Totty...I have edited the query above, I hope it will be stable, and if not, then please do mention what unexpected behaviour you observe.

Comment: ok, im testing. until now it's all right. But I'm thinking to put another union to get all possible values for the type of fk (that I didn't specified)

Comment: it's better to put UNION ALL instead of only UNION

Answer (score 0):

It acts as an inner join because the fields are referenced in the WHERE clause (even though you are checking for NULL): if you move your constraint to the join, it should work. You could probably remove the null checks as well.

```
select code, time_fk1, time_fk2 
    from table as fk1 
    left join table as fk2 
    on fk1.code=fk2.code 
      and (fk1.fk=1 or fk1.fk is null) and (fk2.fk=2 or fk2.fk is null)
```